# Most kinds of traffic blocked while in VPN

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, windows-firewall

Important: This problem is specific to one computer. The VPN works fine for a wide variety of users and devices. I have other Windows 10 machines in my home that work with this VPN, plus Android and iOS devices.

The VPN adapter (using [instructions found on this page](https://documentation.meraki.com/MX-Z/Client_VPN/Client_VPN_OS_Configuration#Windows_10)) on my Windows 10 PC connects fine to our Meraki VPN, but once it's connected, most traffic is blocked.

**What I CAN do:**

- Log in to the VPN
- Ping anything on the intranet or internet by IP **or name**. This does not appear to be a DNS problem

**What I cannot do:**

- Use HTTP either by IP or name
- Use RDP either by IP or name

This image tells the story. I was logged in to the VPN when I took this screenshot. Chrome, on the left, can't find google.com. But pinging google.com, on the right, works.

[image: browser error message next to ping results]

**What I've tried:**

- Different browsers
- Switching antivirus suites (I suspected this was Norton's fault, but I switched to BitDefender and it still happens)
- Looking through Windows Firewall rules - didn't see anything that seemed to be related, although maybe I'm just missing it

Comment: have you tried logging into that same account on a different PC? or is this issue bound to the PC and not a user account?

Comment: It definitely seems to be limited to the PC. The same account works on my laptop and phone.